# Defining a Variable Inside a Lambda

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

Is there any way I can assign a variable like this in a lambda?

```
(lambda x,y=[1]*x: both variables x and y would be used and modified in here)(input())
```

Or is there another way that I can assign a variable y to be a list the size of x?  The whole program has to be written in in one line without semicolons, so declaring a variable outside of the lambda won't help.

For example, can something like this be achieved?

```
x=input()
y=[1]*x
for i in xrange(2,int(x**.5)+2):
        if y[i]:
            for j in xrange(i*i,x,i):
                y[j]=0
```

These would be the x and y values, the other stuff I could probably figure out

Comment: This is too confusing a question for me, can you give an explicit example? Why not just substitute everywhere you see "y" inside the function for [1]*x, since y is only meaningful inside the lambda function's scope? Or are you trying to set it outside it's own scope, which is itself not too meaningful? If so, what is it? Why can't you use multiple lines? Code golf (not appropriate here)? 8 bytes of ROM? Can you use setattr instead? In short, the assignment syntax is not defined, no.

Comment: I believe lambda function bodies are constrained to be expressions, which precludes variable assignment.  If you want to include statements in the function body (assignment or otherwise), your best bet is to define a named function, then use that in place of the lambda.

Comment: @TomKarzes That's sort of true, in that they are strongly discouraged and the assignment syntax is invalid. You can hack it though if you have good reason to, like using setattr on an object, or embedding an exec call. But without a clearer question, it's hard to say...

Comment: The question is edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this be permitted?

```
>>> f = lambda x,y=None: (x, [1]*x if y is None else y)
>>> f(10, [1, 1, 1])
(10, [1, 1, 1])
>>> f(15)
(15, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

This example simply evaluates to a tuple containing the arguments, achieving the default argument value for y with an inline if statement.

Immediate call without assignment of the lambda (assuming Python 2 `input()` behaviour):

```
>>> (lambda x,y=None: (x, [1]*x if y is None else y))(input("x? : "))
x? : 5
(5, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: It seems to work well. Do you know how I could pass those values returned into another lambda function? For example `(lambda a,b:list(a)+b)(lambda x,y=None: (x, [1]*x if y is None else y))(input("x? : "))` without it giving an argument error?

Comment: @BobMarshall: yes, unpack the result of the nested `lambda` expression with `*` before passing it to the outer `lambda`. For your example: `(lambda a,b:[a]+b)(*(lambda x,y=None: (x, [1]*x if y is None else y))(input("x? : ")))`.